# Get recent inserted Id and send in to another controllers view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

**EDITED:**
I have Created CRUD Functions for each Modals and now i am trying to get recent Inserted Id and use it in different view.
Here is what I have tried so far

---

I have created 2 classes(Layer based) for CRUD function for each ContextEntities db to practice pure OOP recursive approach and following is the code.

### 1. Access Layer

**ViolatorDB**

```
public class ViolatorDB
{
    private TPCAEntities db;
    public ViolatorDB()
    {
        db = new TPCAEntities();
    }
    public IEnumerable<tbl_Violator> GetALL()
    {
        return db.tbl_Violator.ToList();
    }
    public tbl_Violator GetByID(int id)
    {
        return db.tbl_Violator.Find(id);
    }
    public void Insert(tbl_Violator Violator)
    {
        db.tbl_Violator.Add(Violator);
        Save();
    }
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        tbl_Violator Violator = db.tbl_Violator.Find(id);
        db.tbl_Violator.Remove(Violator);
        Save();
    }
    public void Update(tbl_Violator Violator)
    {
        db.Entry(Violator).State = EntityState.Modified;
        Save();
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

}
```

### 2. Logic Layer

**ViolatorBs**

```
 public class ViolatorBs
{
    private ViolatorDB objDb;
    public ViolatorBs()
    {
        objDb = new ViolatorDB();
    }
    public IEnumerable<tbl_Violator> GetALL()
    {
        return objDb.GetALL();
    }
    public tbl_Violator GetByID(int id)
    {
        return objDb.GetByID(id);
    }
    public void Insert(tbl_Violator Violator)
    {
        objDb.Insert(Violator);
    }
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        objDb.Delete(id);
    }
    public void Update(tbl_Violator Vioaltor)
    {
        objDb.Update(Vioaltor);
    }
}
```

And Finally using Logic Layer functions in **presentation Layer**.Here insertion is performed as:

```
    public class CreateViolatorController : Controller
{
    public TPCAEntities db = new TPCAEntities();
    private ViolatorBs objBs;
    public CreateViolatorController()
    {
        objBs = new ViolatorBs();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var voilator = new tbl_Violator();
         voilator=db.tbl_Violator.Add(voilator);

        ViewBag.id = voilator.VID;            

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(tbl_Violator Violator)
    {

        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                objBs.Insert(Violator);

                TempData["Msg"] = "Violator Created successfully";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                return View("Index");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["Msg"] = "Failed..." + ex.Message + " " + ex.ToString();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
}
```

Now here is the main part how do i get perticuller inserted id in another controller named **Dues** while performing insertion ?

In sqlqery I would have used @@IDENTITY but in Entity Framework I'm not sure.
I'm new to mvc framework any suggestion or help is appreciated Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You might want to add what have you tried so far.

Comment: yes i have tried.I have no clue what approach should i use.
W8 let me Update My code that I have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to add and save your table as you have done this already in your voilatorDB class just fetch the last id like following

```
    var id = yourTableName.Id;
db.yourTableName.find(id);
```

Or you can simply write one line code to achive that using VoilatorBs class function

```
GetbyID(id);
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you save your db context the id is populated back to your entity by EF automatically.

for example.

```
using(var context = new DbContext())
{
  var employee = new Employee(); //this has an id property
  context.Employees.Add(employee);
  context.SaveChanges();
  var id = employee.id; // you will find the id here populated by EF
}
```

Comment: i am saving db while using insert function so what do i do then ?

Comment: kindly look at my code I have uploaded I want tlb_Voilator.id to insert it in tbl_Dues.

Comment: Instead of using ViewBag you can use TempData to persist values across redirects in MVC, see here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.aspx